# VK API получение постов конкретного пользователя

Tags: c#, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Составляю запрос на сервер вк, используя VK API. Есть группа в вк, нужно получить все посты в данной группе определенного пользователя (created_by). Использую C# string.

Comment: добро пожаловать на [ru.so]! сформулируйте, пожалуйста, сам **вопрос**. внести изменения можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса. (просьба написать код — это не вопрос).

Answer (score 1):

```
// #r "\Newtonsoft.Json\7.0.1\lib\net45\Newtonsoft.Json.dll"
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System.Net;

IEnumerable<JToken> wall(int id, int offset, int count) { // для групп указать -id
  var m = "https://api.vk.com/method/wall.get";
  var p = $"?owner_id={id}&extended=0&v=5.44&offset={offset}&count={count}";
  var c = new WebClient() { Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8 };
  var s = c.DownloadString(m + p);
  return JObject.Parse(s)["response"]["items"];
}
```

---

```
foreach (var itm in wall(1, 0, 5))  // 5-ть записей со стены vk.com/id1
  Console.WriteLine(itm["from_id"] + " " + itm["text"]);
```